# Android Library Project Plugin Name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

in the shorter history the Android Gradle based builds need change the names for the plugins.
Like

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Anyone can tell me the new plugin name for library projects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Comment: thx, that was pretty easy, could not find the infos in the docs at all.